# Can't download files to HTC One X

Tags: downloading

My phone has stopped allowing me to download any files to the download folder on my sdcard. The download folder is now empty too which it wasn't before and I never deleted the files manually. Its a HTC One X+ so the sdcard is internal rather than an sdcard I've provided. I can still download from the Play Store, update apps or install new ones but anything I try and download through any browser fails regardless of file type. If I browse to the download folder in root browser I can't create a new folder, operation failed. I can create new folders in the sdcard just not in download folder of sdcard. I'm assuming a mount problem of some sort?

Comment: Could you provide some error messages? Or a logcat snippet?

Comment: This is usually related to a corrupted FAT partition (I think the HOX+ uses FAT32 for the internal sdcard). I would back up everything off your "sdcard" and then format it.